# Solidity - Function Selector Loading onto the stack: why DIV instead of SHR?

Tags: solidity, evm, opcode

I'm currently learning about how the function selector is loaded from calldata. The algorithm is like so:

```
PUSH4 ffffffff
PUSH29 0100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
PUSH1 00
CALLDATALOAD
DIV
AND
```

Which results in the selector being loaded from calldata shifted to the right on the stack. This comes to a total of 20 gas.
What I don't understand is why SHR isn't just used directly?
ie.

```
PUSH0
CALLDATALOAD
PUSH1 E0 // 224 in hex. 28 bytes to the right
SHR
```

Which comes to 11 gas, with the same single-value on the stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is probably due to using non-updated documentation or tutorials, which refers to an old Solidity compiler.

The procedure you mention using `SHR` has been in place as default for the compiler, with or without optimization enabled, for more than four years.

I did some tests, and I can say `solc@0.5.5`, [released on March 5th, 2019](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/releases/tag/v0.5.5), starts to use that procedure, while `solc@0.5.4` and below use the old version.

Side note. Nothing stops you from using the old selector procedure, but as you mentioned, you don't gain anything from that.

Comment: Thanks, it was indeed that the tutorial I was following was using compiler version 0.4.24. Still, interesting that this was ever the procedure at all.

Comment: @riordant mark it as an answer if this solved your query. thanks:)